# graphics card and monitor not recognized

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a MSI NVIDIA GTX770 - N770 TF 2GD5/OC that is not being recongnized by my windows 7 64 System.

The display adapter shows a warning in device manager and opening the nvidia control panel  doesn't open .. (previously it said that you are correctly not using a monitor connected to a nvidia gpu"

Also my monitor shows "Default Monitor" instead of my Benq monitor.

What I've tried so far:

Uninstall drivers completely and throughly (including registry keys etc and using multiple methods).. reinstalling the correct drivers and older drivers.. no success.

I might add that I do not have a graphics card option in my bios so maybe it has something with the computer not detecting it?

Anything else I can try?

Comment: Did you use driver sweep in safe mode to completely wipe all display drivers before re-installing?

Comment: i didn't use driver sweep but I used a tool called "Display Driver Uninstaller" instead and it does it's thing in safe mode

Comment: You've mentioned changing registry keys. Maybe you messed something up by doing that. Did you back up your registry before making the changes?

Comment: didn't backup but the only things I deleted where the keys named NVIDIA.. I also tried doing a system restore.. and the problem persists..

Comment: I'm not too sure then tbh. I'm assuming you've tried all of the ports on the graphics card, with different cables?

Comment: I haven't tried physically moving to another port but I'll try that next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being my oculus dk2 display drivers that were causing issues. After uninstalling all the oculus drivers the card works!